# why is the text green in my code listing?

Tags: listings, code, code-snippets

I use

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Type readable_t, writable_t
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want the text color to be **black**, but instead I get green:

[image]

Comment: you have a `\lstset{...}` with the color definition in your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. In this case, we cannot answer your question without seeing the rest of your document. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!